# How to reload the component life cycle when reusing component in react-natvie?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Suppose the app have a menu lists on the left, every menu reuses same  content component on the right.(I use react-redux)

If I click the menu, the menu state update and the content component will load different data and do some other actions. But after the first load the content component will not execute componentWillMount, componentDidMount,it only has componentWillReceiveProps...etc. It is complex to handle the similar state. I hope the component will reload every time so that I can handle the state in componentDidMount. Is it about Class and Instance ? I hope get some good advice.

I have solved previous problem,but there is a bug about RefreshControl of  ScrollView or ListView. Next is the code of content component:

```
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>

                    <ListView
                        <RefreshControl
                            refreshing = {tableFetching || refreshTable}
                            onRefresh = {this._onRefresh}
                            tintColor = "gray"
                            title = "loading..." />
                        enableEmptySections = {true}
                        dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(tableData)}
                        renderRow={this.renderRow}
                        style={{flex: 1}} />


                </View>
```

When the component load firstly, the RefreshControl shows normally. But when I change the menu, the component update and load the new datas, the RefreshControl indicator doesn't show , it scroll to the above not to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see is that you are not able to manage the state. First of all componentWillMount and componentDidMount will work only for the first time until you don't move it out from the navigator stack(popRoute). In your case you don't want to pop the route to manage state so you can use other lifecycle components such as componentWillRecieveProps(),shouldComponentUpdate() etc. I have one more rescue plan for you, the forceUpdate() function which will update the component forcefully, but usage of it is prohibited until and unless there is no otherway.

Cheers:)

Comment: You mean that I can make it reload by navigator?   I have used navigator in the outer container, the menu page is just a route.  So  can I  also use navigator in the menu ?

Comment: please can you add your code to the question so that it become easy for me to understand

Comment: sorry for the late reply because of my network in China. I have solved the problem,  just using componentWillRecieveProps. But there is a problem that when I change the menu, ListView RefreshControl indicator  doesn't show normally. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I did get you, could you please explain me that what is happening exactly with listview?

Comment: I have updated the question,or I can email you the completed code.

Comment: I got it, You can not define scrollview outside listview. Whenever listview is encapsulated in scrollview then events gets triggered automatically. For example sometimes onendreached api of listview can also get triggered..

Comment: It doesn't work if I use View instead of ScrollView and add RefreshControl in ListView.

Comment: add refresh not working in the listview? can you please update the answer with this code.

Comment: In current menu, it  does work  and the refresh indicator show normally when I pull down to trigger the onRefresh event. But when changing the menu to load the data and update the <ListView>,  everything is ok but the position of the refresh indicator. In fact if I pull down  a little , I can see it.

Comment: I think there is style issue maybe. try removing flex in view and listview

Comment: onmenu click, does now your refresh control is getting triggered automatically?

Comment: yes, onmenu click I change the menu state in redux reducer,  then trigger ajax action and change the fetching state as true to control the refreshing attribute.  It's not about the style, so I'm finding another component to replace the native...